# Determining which NSView instance initiated a mouseDown:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, reflection, nsview, introspection

I have a gameboard with 25 tiles of myGameTile, a subclass of NSView.
In mouseDown: I want to determine which tile I clicked on and set an ivar to a representative value.

e.g. If I click on tile 12, set clickedTile to "12" or some value that uniquely represents that particular instance.

I'm open anything from the integer value 12 all the way to some sort of introspection/reflection, though built-in features and elegance are preferable to hacks, runtime wrappers, and modification.  Still, I'm aware that I may have no choice but to rely on those solutions, so please to answer with those as well.  I'd like to know all my options.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a poorly-titled question. I'd suggest changing it to something like "Determining which subview in a gameboard was clicked". Asking "which instance self is" makes little sense at first glance.

Answer (score 5):

You could subclass NSView and override the [tag method](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/tag), as written in the documentation.

Comment: He already said that he has subclassed NSView... That said, setting the tag is probably a very simple way to know which view was clicked. It would require manually assigning a tag to each view in the desired order, but this seems like a very workable solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

You have several possibilities:

If you handle the mouseDown in the Tile view, then you need to map self to the tile ID.  There are three easy ways to do this:

- Pre configure Tile.tag to be the tile ID, then use self.tag.
- Search for Tile in the array of Tiles to find the index [parent.tiles indexOfObject:self]
- Create a dictionary mapping Tile or tile ID [[parent.tiles objectForKey:self] intValue]

Clearly, using the tag is the easiest, as long as you are not using the tag for anything else.

Alternatively, you could implement hitTest on the parent view, and return the parent view, and then handle the mouseDown in the parent view.  Then mouseDown will know where the hit is and hence which tile it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think hitTest: will do what you want.  Something like this:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSPoint aPoint = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    NSView* viewHit = [self hitTest:aPoint];
    if( viewHit != nil && viewHit != self ) {
        // viewHit is our tile.
    }
}
```

Comment: NSView inherits from NSResponder, so you probably shouldn't have to manually test this — the documentation for -hitTest: says "This method is used primarily by an NSWindow object to determine which view should receive a mouse-down event. You’d rarely need to invoke this method, but you might want to override it to have a view object hide mouse-down events from its subviews." If the -mouseDown: method is called on an NSView, it means that view was determined to be the one that should respond to the event.